# replacing a variable in shell script using perl

Tags: perl, shell

I have a variable in a shell script,

```
var=1234_number
```

I want to replace all other than integer of $var .. how can I do it using a perl onliner?

Comment: Please clarify - probably by showing the required output, and any exclusions.  The 'replace all other than integer of $var' is not easily understood.

Comment: I'm petty sure that the dollar sign is not wanted in '$var=1234'.  Are you asking for something to edit the shell script file as a whole, or are you asking to strip non-digits from the variable as an action within the shell script?  What if the value is currently '1234_abc_5678'?

Comment: You can't *replace* characters in an environment variable in Perl. It can create the proper expression so that your shell can do it when it takes it back from Perl. For Korn shell and Bash, given the case you show: you could just do `var=${var%%_*}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use anything but the shell for this

```
var=1234_abcd
var=${var%_*}
echo $var  # => 1234
```

See 'Parameter Expansion' in the bash manual.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something to edit the shell script, in which case, this might be sufficient:

```
perl -i.bak -e 's/\b(var=\d+).*/$1/' shellscript.sh
```

The '`-i`' overwrites the original file, saving a copy in shellscript.sh.bak; the substitute command finds assignments to 'var' (and not any longer name ending 'var') followed by an equals sign, some digits, and any non-digits, and leaves behind just the assignment of digits.

In the example, it gives:

```
var=1234
```

Note that the Perl regex is not foolproof - it will mangle this (dropping the closing brace).

```
: ${var=1234_number}
```

Dealing with all such possible variants is <s>extremely</s> fairly tricky:

```
echo $var=$other
```

OTOH, you might be looking to eliminate digits from a variable within a shell script, in which case:

```
var=$(echo $var | perl -e 's/\D//g')
```

You could also use 'sed' for the job:

```
var=$(echo $var | sed 's/[^0-9]//g')
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan...
I just wanted to get the output as 1234
var=$(echo $var | perl -e 's/\D//g') - this did the work :)
sorry for the typo , $var=1234